# Como separar una cadena string por espacios?

Tags: java, string

En codigo Java, quiero saber como puedo separar una cadena de texto por cada espacio que exista en ella.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el metodo `split()` que separa la cadena por el string especificado en el parametro:

```
String[] datos = "hola mundo como estas".split(" ");

for(String item : datos)
{
  System.out.println(item);
}
```

Comment: a mi de esta forma solo me coge la primera palabra y el resto no las recoge

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta función:

se  esta utilizando sobre un string S

```
s="Separar por espacios"
s.split(" ");
```

la función split() se puede utilizar no solo para un caracter si no para varios.

Ejemplo:

```
String cadena = "texto de que quieras";
String delimitadores= "[ .,;?!¡¿\'\"\\[\\]]+";
String[] palabrasSeparadas = cadena.split(delimitadores);
```